# Xslt get text between strings with different rules for different languages

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-parsing

I'm parsing Html page using `xslt`. 
On page there are one peace of html from which I want to receive publisher name

```
<div>
    <span class="publisher_name">by xxx from TripAdvisor</span>
</div>
```

To parse it I use next code:

```
<xsl:variable name="publisherTextNode" select=".//span[@class='publisher_name'][1]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$publisherTextNode">
        <Publisher>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-trim">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-before(substring-after($publisherTextNode, 'by'), 'from')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
         </Publisher>
    </xsl:if>
```

So it should select text between `by` and `from`. As result it should be `xxx`

But here is problem for language that isn't `English`.

In case of Spanish html looks like

```
<span class="publisher_name">por xxx de TripAdvisor</span>
```

and `xslt` returns `string.Empty` cause it cannot find `by` string.

So I want to add similar rule to support Spanish string also like

```
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-before(substring-after($publisherTextNode, 'por'), 'de')" />
```

Can I somehow add this 2 rules to existing xslt schema (maybe check if first rule returns string.Empty then use 2nd rule?) or create separate one for different languages?

---

```
  <xsl:template name="string-trim">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />
<xsl:call-template name="string-rtrim">
  <xsl:with-param name="string">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-ltrim">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string" />
      <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

```
<xsl:template name="string-ltrim">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />

<xsl:if test="string-length($string) &gt; 0">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($trim, substring($string, 1, 1))">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-ltrim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 2)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

```
  <xsl:template name="string-rtrim">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:param name="trim" select="$whitespace" />

<xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($string)" />

<xsl:if test="$length &gt; 0">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($trim, substring($string, $length, 1))">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-rtrim">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 1, $length - 1)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="trim"   select="$trim" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: As an aside, this can also be done using xquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:call-template name="string-trim">
    <xsl:with-param name="string">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($publisherTextNode, 'by ') and contains($publisherTextNode, ' from')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($publisherTextNode, 'by '), ' from')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($publisherTextNode, 'por ') and contains($publisherTextNode, ' de')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($publisherTextNode, 'por '), ' de')" />
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

---

Note that there is a slight chance of getting a false positive on the tests.

Comment: Thx, it's working... but yes, your note is important)

Comment: If your examples are indicative, you could reduce the chance by replacing `contains()` in the first condition with `starts-with()`.